# Markdownize an Emacs buffer

Tags: emacs, markdown

I am looking for a Markdown variant of the [Htmlize](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Htmlize) addon.

The idea is simple: say, you wish to publish code to a GIST on GitHub, or any place which supports Markdown. You type your code in Emacs, do `M-x markdownize-buffer` and you get a new buffer containing the full Markdown markup.

Anybody knows if such an addon exists?

Comment: If you want to publish code in a Gist, you don't use Markdown.  You just copy the code into the Gist.  Markdown in a Gist is for documentation, not code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markdown isn't powerful enough to generate span classes. To do this, you need to drop down into pure HTML.

Htmlize will generate a syntax-highlighted version of your code based on your current Emacs theme settings. Take a look at the generated markup: it does this by generating both DOM elements and styles to replicate your current syntax highlighting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<!-- Created by htmlize-1.36 in css mode. -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>sha1test.rb</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
      body {
        color: #eeeeec;
        background-color: #2e3434;
      }
      .comment {
        /* font-lock-comment-face */
        color: #888a85;
      }
      .comment-delimiter {
        /* font-lock-comment-delimiter-face */
        color: #888a85;
      }
    /* [...] */
    -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>
require <span class="string">'digest/sha1'</span>

<span class="type">SLICE_SIZE</span> = 20

<span class="keyword">def</span> <span class="function-name">myhash</span>(input)
  <span class="type">Digest</span>::<span class="type">SHA1</span>.hexdigest(input).slice(0,<span class="type">SLICE_SIZE</span>)
<span class="keyword">end</span>

hashmap = {}
inputs = 0
unique_inputs = 0
<span class="type">ARGF</span>.each <span class="keyword">do</span> |line, idx|
[...]
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: htmlized buffer: browser screenshot]

Markdown can't replicate the kind of information here. It's good for translating semantic plain-text into semantic markup (i.e. headers should turn into H1 or H2, `**text**` should generate `<strong>text</strong>`, etc.). Which lines of your Emacs buffer are headers? Which should translate into `<em>` tags?

Comment: I know the advantages of Htmlize; been using it happily for years. Thing is, I had no idea that Markdown couldn't do that, not even close to Htmlize. Thanks.